# Unable to store dropdown list items generated through search textfield in List in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have send a searchable keyword through send keys in search text field of youtube. But when the drop down emerge below search textfield, I am unable to store the dropdown items in List and click anyone of them. I am getting '0' as a result in printing list size.

```
package SomeBasicAutomationPractice;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Practice_dynamic_xpath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\VivekAutomationPractice\\src\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys("selenium");
     List<WebElement> li=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'sbse')]"));
    System.out.println(li.size());
    li.get(2).click();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code my friend. If this code helps you then I request you to mark it as accepted. This is how Stackoverflow works my friend :)

```
    static{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Sangeeta-Laptop\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (3)\\chromedriver.exe");
    }
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    String urlBase = "https://www.youtube.com";

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        driver.get(urlBase);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }


    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys("selenium");
          Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         List<WebElement> li=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'sbse')]"));
         Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(li.size());

    }

    @org.testng.annotations.AfterTest
    public void AfterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me share the project code then. Please wait for a while.

Comment: Ok I will wait, Thanks.

Comment: Please check the updated comment. I have added the code there. Please let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: You must have java 1.8 or newer installed in your system in order to use the first static block. if you do not have, then remove static block and put the code in BeforeTest :)

Comment: I am a beginner in automation, So I don't know what is testng annotations, I have copy pasted the code that is in the  @Test block to replace with the old code, But still no success.

Comment: Just to confirm is the code successfully running at your end?

Comment: Yes it is running successfully. Let me just share the whole maven project. You just need to add that maven project in your IDE e.g. eclipse and then you can run it as maven test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213680/discussion-between-rapper-ab-and-rohn-kerry).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#results ol#search-results>li h3>a"));

Comment: Can you make your answer more simple please, As I am not able to understand it.Thanks.